# How to run Django channels test?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-channels

I am following the tutorial here https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html

It's telling me how to write a test, but it's not telling me how to run it.

Comment: You can refer to the Django documentation for general Django testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Django Channels requires PyTest due to async requirements. If you read through PyTest documentation the command to run the tests is:

```
    $ pytest
```

I haven't actually used Channels, so this may require more setup. The documentation for PyTest: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/

You might also consider putting in a request for Django Channels to explicitly link to this in their tutorial.